# How to make same enum in different schemas without code duplication in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

I have `schema1.myenum` and want it to also be available as `schema2.myenum` ideally without code duplication.

Comment: Have you tried just using it? As long as an account has permissions on a schema, it can use its objects in queries

Comment: I did, it worked but I still am curious.

Comment: Calling `schema1.MyEnum` as `Schema2.MyEnum` is aliasing, not reuse. You're already reusing a single Enum definition. You can avoid writing `schema1.MyEnum` by putting `schema1` in [the search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH). I don't think it's worth it though, just to avoid writing `schema1`.